# Weight vs. Speed for Road Rage/Racing

Tags: burnout-3

In Burnout 3, the Road Rage game mode, you are tasked with busting other cars.  In racing, you are tasked with getting to the finish line fastest, and you can also take out cars.
Each car has a weight value and a speed value.

My question is, what is the best blend?  What gives you the most destructibility while at the same time making sure you don't come in dead last speed-wise?

(I am not looking for an opinion; I am looking for a specific speed and weight in which I can still catch up to the lead car, but still take out other cars without being slammed off the road)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing for around 60 hours in Race mode, I have found that an equal or as close to equal as possible weight vs. speed ratio is of the greatest benefit.

In 50 races as a speed favored car, I crashed an average of 2 times more per race(4 times) as compared to the others.

In 50 races as a weight favored car, I came in second and third twice as much as first as compared to the others.

In 50 races as a balanced car, I came in second and first both 40% of the time, and I came in third 20% of the time, I and I crashed an average of 3 times per race.

All of this data suggests that an even leveled car would provide the maximum survivability t0 speed ratio.